# How to force restart after uninstall for a Basic MSI Project in InstallShield 2009 Premier

Tags: uninstallation, restart, installshield-2009

**InstallShield 2009 Premier, Basic MSI Project**:
After uninstall completes, I want to **force restart** the computer. How?

Googling found, i have to set '**REBOOTPROMPT**' TO 'S' or 'R' and the "**Reboot**" property.

How to set these properties and with what values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the Solution

1. You have to **let InstallShield know that you want a reboot**.
   **How?**: From 'Installation Designer' tab -> 'Behavior and Logic' -> 'Custom Actions and Sequences' -> 'Sequences' -> 'Installation' -> 'Execute' -> '**ScheduleReboot**' set the value of 'Conditions' to "NOT REMOVE" (with out the inverted commas) if you want the reboot to happen after install and to "REMOVE" if after uninstall.
2. So up to now after install/uninstall the **installer would show a warning message** something like "... click ok to restart your machine now or cancel to restart later...". Now if you don't want to show this warning message even do step 3.
3. Go to 'Installation Designer' tab -> 'Behavior and Logic' -> '**Property Manager**', a table would be open. Now add/edit the (Name, Value) pair with (**REBOOTPROMPT, Suppress**). This would suppress the message.