# InstallShield - restart option after installation completes

Tags: installshield

How can I add a 'restart' checkbox after instalation completes in my InstallShield project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this previous SO answer does the trick: [How to force restart after uninstall for a Basic MSI Project in InstallShield 2009 Premier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681775/how-to-force-restart-after-uninstall-for-a-basic-msi-project-in-installshield-200/2688718#2688718)

Note that i haven't flagged this as a duplicate because there are different flavors of InstallShield and you haven't said which you are using.

**Edit:** the InstallShield doco also suggests using the SdFinishReboot dialog which is instantiated via script. Here are a couple of links: [SdFinishReboot](http://support.installshield.com/kb/isp/funcref/LangrefSdFinishReboot.htm), [SdFinishReboot sample](http://support.installshield.com/kb/isp/funcref/LangrefSdFinishReboot_example.htm)

Comment: The link is great and I'm also interested in the official info from the InstallShield help file. Thanks.