# Intallshield Programming - Reboot behavior - Windows does not ask user to close open files before restart

Tags: windows, windows-7, installshield, restart, reboot

My engineer send me 2 versions of installation software for evaluation (made with Installshield), which he said he has made no changes to the `Restart settings`, but just changes messages in `dialog boxes`.

However, when tested on `Win 8` and `Win 7`

1. One version will restart Windows while Windows does not prompt there are applications with open files
2. One version will attempt to restart Windows, but then Windows will prompt there are applications with open files

I am not a programmer, but I would like to know what may be possible cause of this difference?  And what is the setting which can cause the 2 different restart behavior.

Then I would like to know how can I test the installation software to make sure it is designed properly and make Windows attempts to `restart` properly such that it won't force a `restart` if there is any open files; after all, making users lose their work is very bad.

Thank you very much.
John

Answer (score -1):

If your Installer installs any prerequisites, it may be possible that the reboot is required to install the prerequisite properly. So it is possible that the prerequisite would be installed when you wold have installed your product for the first time and it would have asked for the 'Restart'. And now as the prerequisite is installed, no need to reinstall it so 'Reboot' is not required.
If this is the case, you can go to'Application Data' > 'Redistributables' and edit the prerequisite. Here you can specify appropriate condition to handle the 'Restart' behavior.

If your application doesn't install prerequisite and it is your product that requires a reboot, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688718/1189241) answer. You can configure a property to handle the 'Restart' properly.