# Is there anyway to force InstallShield to stop if a file is not overwritten?

Tags: file, installshield, overwrite

During upgrade, InstallShield sometimes cannot overwrite an old .exe file because someone run that file during the upgrading process.

The problem is InstallShield didn't stop or give a warning/error message. It just skips that file and update other files then announce upgrading success.

Is there a way to produce an error message or forcefully stop the installer when this happen ?

Comment: Usually it's vise-versa Installer stops (kills) executable after warning. Easy to identify if your `exe` is running and kill it or have the method in the executable to shut down. `dll` is more complecated and sometimes impossible to unload from all applications. In this case installer still installs upgrade, but after request re-boot.

Comment: I also had cases with dll not replacing in the path due to being used by another application, but installer doesn't request a re-boot and just installs upgrade.

Comment: You may force reboot at the end if needed ... [How to force restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681775/how-to-force-restart-after-uninstall-for-a-basic-msi-project-in-installshield-20)

Comment: If this is MSI based, capture a verbose log and look for hints related to the file in question. If it is InstallScript based, have you considered implementing the [OnFileLocked](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefOnFileLocked.htm) event?

Comment: As Urman says, we need to know if this is MSI or not? Are you installing in silent mode or full GUI mode?

Comment: It is installed in full GUI mode, Installscript project. I have tried various command like /verbose"D:/setup.log" or /v"/l*v D:/msi.log" and they doesn't produce a single log. This project need various input information so it cannot be run in silent mode.